# Javascript regex- How to match xpaths

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a regex for matching xpaths generated by firebug, cna some one help me with that, an example xpath is:

```
.//*[@id='tab-HOME']/li[2]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]/span[2]/span/span
.//*[@id='any_possible_id']/span/span[2]/span/span
```

Now keeping in mind the names alowed for id's in javascript what can be the possible regex. I want to match

```
.//*[@id='any_possible_id']/li
```

Here is what I tried:

```
alert(/^\.\/\/\*\[[@id=]*\]/.test(xpath));
```

certainly incomplete.

Comment: Do you want only the id ?

Comment: what is the meaning of 'I want to match `.//*[@id='any_possible_id']/li`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^\]]+` after the id to match until the next `]` of the `[@id=...]`

```
alert(/^\.\/\/\*\[@id=[^\]]+\]\/li/.test(xpath));
```

If you do not want to match only for `../li` then remove the `li` from the regex.